# Docker fciwrap permission denied

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

So I´ve been trying to make fciwrap to take screenshots of the streams in my nginx server. But I just keep getting permission denied on the socket of fciwrap. I just want to take a screenshot of my streams for me via web show a preview of the stream. I dont know id there is any better way to achieve this.

Log:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2024:20:17:27 +0000] "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test" "PostmanRuntime/7.36.1"
2024/01/20 20:17:27 [crit] 19#19: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test"
```

Nginx.conf

```
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # puerto por defecto para rtmp

        application live {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;
            hls_fragment 5s; # default 5s
            hls_playlist_length 30s; # default 30s
            # para permitir CORS
            # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

            # authentication
            on_publish http://auth_server:8000/auth;
        }
    }
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            root /www;
        }

        location /hls {
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                application/octet-stream ts;
            }
            root /tmp;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

            # para permitir CORS
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;

            # para permitir CORS
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /thumbnail/ {
         # Disable gzip (it makes scripts feel slower since they have to complete
         # before getting gzipped)
         gzip off;
         # Set the root to /usr/share/nginx
         # (inside this location this means that we are
         # giving access to the files under /usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin)
         root /usr/share/nginx;
         # Fastcgi socket
         fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
         # Fastcgi parameters, include the standard ones
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         # Adjust non standard parameters (SCRIPT_FILENAME)
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/nginx-rtmp

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y fcgiwrap
RUN update-rc.d fcgiwrap defaults 20
# RUN sed -i 's/www-data/nginx/g' /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY index.html /www/

COPY thumbnail.cgi /usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi
RUN  chmod +x  /usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi

# Creamos el archivo del socket y le damos permisos de todo(porque solo se crea cuando se inicia)
RUN touch /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket && chmod 777 /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket

CMD /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap start && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

It all works if after I've done docker compose up I give the permissions trough the terminal.

[image]

Then when I've given permissions and I do a normal request.

http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test

I get this error in the logs

```
2024/01/20 21:04:33 [error] 19#19: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME (or SCRIPT_FILENAME) set and is the script executable?" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test"
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: I've managged to get it online but now when I make a request I get this error

2024/01/20 23:07:04 [error] 21#21: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot execute script (/usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test"